# Getting "`find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem cocoapods" error while pod install

Tags: ruby, react-native, cocoapods

I am getting `'find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem cocoapods` error while doing pod install. I tried the solutions on Stackoverflow but I can't fix it. How can I solve it?

[image]

I see there are 2 different versions of Ruby. Is my problem related to this situation?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Restart Your Mac

```
Run sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Then

```
sudo gem update --system
sudo gem install cocoapods -n/usr/local/bin
```